# Как сделать обратный loop | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Как сделать обратный loop в blade?

У меня есть список:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="title">{{sprintf("%'.04d\n", $loop->iteration)}} {{$chapter->title}}</a>

    <span class="time float-right">{{$chapter->created_at}}</span>
    <a href="#" class="del float-right align-items-center">DELETE</a>
</li>
```

Мне выводит:

```
0001  Название 0000:00:00 00:00
0002  Название 0000:00:00 00:00
0003  Название 0000:00:00 00:00
0004  Название 0000:00:00 00:00
```

Как получить:

```
0004  Название 0000:00:00 00:00
0003  Название 0000:00:00 00:00
0002  Название 0000:00:00 00:00
0001  Название 0000:00:00 00:00
```

Не меняя содержимое массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить **$loop->iteration** на **$loop->count-$loop->index**.